# How to change a filename of a file which is in a folder in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone tell how to change a filename of a file which is a located in a folder using PHP?

```
rename("http://localhost/DXXX/photos/".$photoNamepart, "http://localhost/DXXX/photos/".$phototmpNamepart);



Error:Message: rename() [function.rename]: http wrapper does not support renaming
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/tmp/my_file.txt");
```

Comment: Message: rename() [function.rename]: http wrapper does not support renaming

Comment: you cant use urls in rename function, use folder paths instead, like yourRootDir/DXXX/photos/...

Comment: means in localhost whih my yourRootDir? can u tell me ... do i need any helper file

Comment: it is working on my local server but i am accessing other computer's project then what path should i give,when i enter path like " /var/www/html/project_name/assets/img1.jpg " it is giving error no such directory

Answer (score 4):

I guess the [rename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function could help.

Comment: Message: rename() [function.rename]: http wrapper does not support renaming

Answer (score 1):

You're using rename wrong here. `fopen`, `file_get_contents` work fine with URLs - but that's more out of convenience rather than correctness.

For the code that you've written - you first need the absolute path of the file that you want to rename. It will work *only* on the local machine and on files that your webserver is configured to have write-access on.

Let's say your web server root is `WEB_ROOT`,

```
rename(WEB_ROOT."/DXXX/photos/".$photoNamePart, WEB_ROOT."/DXXX/photos/".$photoTempNamePart;
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir1/abc.png', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir2/abc.png')
```

Above code works for me on CI

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_exec('mv former_filename new_filename');
```

you should be having appropriate permissions to do this

Comment: This will work only on linux, its not cross-platform! and on some servers, you are not even allowed to execute `shell_exec` directly. Very unsafe option!

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: yeah, but as I said, not all servers might be supporting it. Some specifically disable it. so things which are not platform independent, as sure not ok, right? some people develop things on windows and do the production on linux, even in that case, things which are not working on windows, its a wrong ideology to develop them that they may not fail in production. thats why sticking to stands and using php.rename function is the right approach to go!

Comment: @linux Nothing wrong with using OS-specific functions as well as with using possible-disabled functions. I am using such things all the time. When a *right* OS have something neat to use (rm -r for example) - I would use it without hesitation. And, special for you: I had to change rename to mv call recently when our project moved to nfs, as rename() failed with "invalid argument" while mv succeeded :-P

Answer (score 0):

This will works properly
copy(getcwd()."/tmp/tmp_file.txt", getcwd()."/tmp/my_file.txt");